# A word sort of like "newsreel" and sort of like "propaganda rag"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of those old U.S. wartime movie-theater newsreels that celebrated victories, but combined with aspersions and taunts on the enemy. "We're great and those guys are idiots." Not necessarily in film format like a newsreel; maybe a printed publication.

Example: The *Mouth of Sauron* Magazine, the ??? of Mordor, celebrates its victory at Minas Morgul and continues to mock the armies of Minas Tirith.

Comment: I remember the films simply being called "propaganda films".

Comment: (Google "ww2 propaganda films".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you will find something along the lines of your requested word if you research [pamphleteer](http://www.memidex.com/pamphleteer) and/or [jingoism](http://www.memidex.com/jingoism). Pamphleteering has a long history in  politics, polemics and propaganda.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, thanks. With any luck there will be some obscure word from the 19th century I can bring back into vogue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation yet to comment, so I'll offer this as an answer...

***[Organ](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/organ?s=t)***

```
a newspaper, magazine, or other means of communicating information,
thoughts, or opinions, especially in behalf of some organization, political
group, or the like.
```

Answer (score 1):

***[Mouthpiece](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mouthpiece)***

```
a person, newspaper, etc., that conveys the opinions or sentiments of
others; spokesperson.
```

Answer (score 0):

The word **promulgate** is a rough synonym between propaganda and dispersal of news. However you will have to pair it with an *adjective* to convey a fuller meaning. i.e. With the the MacCarthy era over, the *obscene* **promulgation** of fear finally came to an end.

Comment: Not really - promulgation is the act not the content - see: www.thefreedictionary.com/promulgate - 1. To make known to the public; popularize or advocate: "Franklin ... first promulgated the idea of free public libraries" (Elaine Wagner).
2. To put (a law, for example) into effect by formal public announcement.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @HotLicks, "Propaganda (film or other medium)" is probably the best fit. But, if you want to insist on falsity, consider **campaign of disinformation**.

> Example: *For months, however, the steady streams of reports about a
>   Russo-Iranian split have been utterly wrong. They are part of a
>   campaign of misinformation (wrong information and analysis) and
>   disinformation (propaganda)*. <[source](http://www.strategic-culture.org/news/2016/03/20/mission-accomplished-fallout-between-iran-and-russia-in-syria.html)>